# MySQL Join makes query slow - can't figure out why

Tags: mysql

I am attaching results of two Explain statements for an old query and the newer version of that query.

Do you see anything that does not make sense or looks wrong? The query became slow(4.5 seconds) after I added tm, tsa and tcd tables.

[image]

Before those three tables were added to the query it was extremely fast (0.001 seconds). Here is what the explain looked like

[image]

tm table has four columns (tm_id (PK), owner_id, manager_id, status), tcd has three columns (tm_id, cd_id, created_date). tm_id and cd_id make a composite primary key and there is another index on cd_id. Same is the case with tsa with three columns (tm_id, smpa_id, created_date) with tm_id and smpa_id being a composite primary key and smpa_id has another index.

What could be the reason for such slowness?

old query:

```
SELECT upcm_id, COUNT( * ) 
FROM user_post_content_master AS upcm
JOIN content_deck AS cd ON cd.cd_id = upcm.cd_id
JOIN social_media_post_account AS smpa ON smpa.smpa_id = upcm.smpa_id
JOIN post_content_master AS pcm ON pcm.pcm_id = upcm.pcm_id
WHERE smpa.user_id =2196
AND upcm.upcm_post_date >=1545891957
AND upcm.upcm_status =1
AND upcm.upcm_post_date >=1546560000
AND upcm.upcm_post_date <=1546732799
GROUP BY upcm.upcm_id
ORDER BY upcm.upcm_post_date ASC
```

New Query:

```
SELECT upcm_id, COUNT( * ) 
FROM user_post_content_master AS upcm
JOIN content_deck AS cd ON cd.cd_id = upcm.cd_id
JOIN social_media_post_account AS smpa ON smpa.smpa_id = upcm.smpa_id
JOIN post_content_master AS pcm ON pcm.pcm_id = upcm.pcm_id
JOIN team_content_deck AS tcd ON ( tcd.cd_id = upcm.cd_id ) 
JOIN team_social_account AS tsa ON tsa.smpa_id = upcm.smpa_id
JOIN team_members AS tm ON tm.team_member_id = tsa.team_member_id
AND tm.team_member_id = tcd.team_member_id
AND tm.owner_id =2196
AND tm.manager_id =2196
AND tm.status =1
WHERE smpa.user_id =2196
AND upcm.upcm_post_date >=1545891957
AND upcm.upcm_status =1
AND upcm.upcm_post_date >=1546560000
AND upcm.upcm_post_date <=1546732799
GROUP BY upcm.upcm_id
ORDER BY upcm.upcm_post_date ASC
```

If I remove the conditions from the tm table, it is fast again. Nothing changed in the joins though.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT upcm_id, COUNT( * ) 
FROM user_post_content_master AS upcm
JOIN content_deck AS cd ON cd.cd_id = upcm.cd_id
JOIN social_media_post_account AS smpa ON smpa.smpa_id = upcm.smpa_id
JOIN post_content_master AS pcm ON pcm.pcm_id = upcm.pcm_id
JOIN team_content_deck AS tcd ON ( tcd.cd_id = upcm.cd_id ) 
JOIN team_social_account AS tsa ON tsa.smpa_id = upcm.smpa_id
JOIN team_members AS tm ON tm.team_member_id = tsa.team_member_id
AND tm.team_member_id = tcd.team_member_id
WHERE smpa.user_id =2196
AND upcm.upcm_post_date >=1545891957
AND upcm.upcm_status =1
AND upcm.upcm_post_date >=1546560000
AND upcm.upcm_post_date <=1546732799
GROUP BY upcm.upcm_id
ORDER BY upcm.upcm_post_date ASC
```

[image]

Comment: You are doing three additional joins, and I'm not surprised that the performance dropped.  Look into setting up indices where appropriate.

Comment: That's why I attached the EXPLAIN screenshot. There are no missing indexes as far as I see it. Do you see any missing @TimBiegeleisen?

Comment: The tm table appears that it might be using a temp table or index, Can't tell for sure as the graphic is cut off. It does appear to be using a filesort instead of index.

Comment: The ref column has const, const which means there is only one value read only once which is the expected behavior. The sort is on upcm table in the old query and it should be on the same in the next one too. I am not sure why it appears next to the tm table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the difference is most likely because the key selected for upcm, old query selected upcm_post_date and new query selected cd_id.

Since the data is not enough, from the name, it seems that cd_id has a much lower cardinality comparing with upcm_post_date.

**Update (Extracted from my comments below):**

One possible reason is because of the sequence of tables mysql decided for the query, content_deck comes before user_post_content_master. Because mysql uses nested-loop algorithm for JOIN, user_post_content_master is in an inner loop for the join.

You have a constant lookup when tm.owner_id is present, which leads MySQL optimizer to decide it win over a range scan.

In the book High Performance MySQL, there is one chapter discussing the query optimization. There is one technique called: join decomposition, i.e., to separate one big join query to small one. One extra benefit is that you can cache some common data.

I am not sure whether Index Hint can help in this case (just hint or force MySQL to use post_data for upcm): SELECT * FROM user_post_content_master USE INDEX (upcm_post_date)

Comment: Yes, post_date would have been perfect as that's how we want it to search. But I can't figure out why did it change to cd_id. Can you see a reason why?

Comment: One possible reason i is because of the sequence of tables mysql decided for the query, content_deck comes before user_post_content_master. Because mysql uses nested-loop algorithm for JOIN, user_post_content_master is in an inner loop for the join.

Comment: This mysql documentation explains how JOIN works: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-loop-joins.html

Comment: One interesting thing here is that if I remove these conditions (AND tm.owner_id = 2196 AND tm.manager_id = 2196 AND tm.status = 1) then it becomes fast again.

Comment: Just added it, Jacob.

Comment: @dinwal this confirmed my suspicion that the index selected for upcm is the reason for the slowness. You have a constant lookup when tm.owner_id is present, which leads MySQL optimizer to decide it win over a range scan.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it from doing that? A way to tell it not to do that?

Comment: In the book High Performance MySQL, there is one chapter discussing the query optimization. There is one technique called: join decomposition, i.e., to separate one big join query to small one. One immediate benefit is that you can cache some common data. Since your result is just a count, can you avoid join some tables?

Comment: I made it count(*) to keep things simpler. Every join is needed.

Comment: I am not sure whether Index Hint can help in this case (just hint or force MySQL to use post_data for upcm): SELECT * FROM user_post_content_master USE INDEX (upcm_post_date).

Comment: That worked. I used index hints and that brought the time down. Thanks.